# js Array.prototype.reduce() что значит =>?

Tags: javascript

Нужно из двумерного массива [1, 2, [3, 4]] сделать одномерный var arr1 = [1, 2,3, 4];

```
arr1.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Так все работает .
А так

```
arr1.reduce(function (acc, val) { acc.concat(val);}, []);
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
Почему во втором случае acc = undefined ?

Comment: [стрелочные функции](https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть тело функции `{ }`, то чтобы вернуть что-то из нее нужно писать return.

В случае с arrow function можно опустить return, если тело функции отсутсвует.

Тоесть функция вернет то что написано после `=>`.

`() => true` тоже самое что `function () { return true })`

```js
const arr1 =  [1, 2, [3, 4]] 
const result = arr1.reduce(function (acc, val) { return acc.concat(val);}, []);
console.log(result)
```